# How to select which ones to install on Android SDK Build tools

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, sdk

[image]I'd like to know which one is important to put check mark on to install.  I've deselected some and my app stopped working so i re intalled all but i dont know their purpose...[image]

Answer (score 0):

Typically the latest production release from Google:

- 28.0.3 (in this case)

re: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/build-tools

Unless you specifically need one of the newer release candidates to target a beta version of Android (build tools 29.x support Android Q (but Xamarin.Android does not currently have a matching alpha/beta release yet)